# JAVA tell if point is in circle with ClickHandler/Canvas

Tags: java, canvas, handler

I am working on checking if the user has clicked inside of a circle on my map. I am attempting to do this by adding a ClickHandler to my canvas, taking the distance between the center of the circle and the clicked point, then checking if that distance is less than the radius of the circle (15). It doesn't appear as if my ClickHandler code is every being hit and I'm not sure why. Clicking the map will not result in any print statements. Breakpoints inside of the ClickHandler definition will not be hit (however other breakpoints inside of getMapEvent() will be hit). All help is appreciated.

```
private void getMapEvent(int day) {
        blinkCanvas.getCanvas().addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            System.out.println("method hit");
            int screenX = event.getScreenX();
            int screenY = event.getScreenY();
            for (MapEvent blink : monthlyBlinks) {
                Point blinkPoint = blinkToScreenXY.get(blink);
                double x = blinkPoint.getX();
                double y = blinkPoint.getY();
                if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - screenX, 2) + Math.pow(y - screenY, 2)) <= 15) {
                    System.out.println(" IN A CIRCLE");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It probably doesn't matter on current computers, but both Math.sqrt and Math.pow are slow and easily avoided for that purpose.

Comment: thanks for the insight- i will refactor once I get it working